# How to get flow to see two string types as incompatible?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I've seen someone do this before, but I can't remember the syntax and I can't seem to find it in the documentation.  I basically want to make two types that both resolve to the same primitive incompatible with one another.  An example should be pretty clear, I want flow to throw an error with this code:

```
type tUsername = string;
type tPassword = string;

function validateUser(user: tUsername, password: tPassword) {
}

validateUser(('foo': tPassword), ('bar': tUsername));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A lot about this here https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/465

And you can solve your problem with **Opaque Type Aliases**

> Opaque type aliases are type aliases that do not allow access to their
>   underlying type outside of the file in which they are defined.

https://flow.org/en/docs/types/opaque-types/

Comment: This still doesn't do what OP is suggesting.

Comment: @Wazeem: Are you sure?

Comment: While the linked resources may address this, putting an *example* of how they do and some *explanation* of how they do would make the answer (much) more useful.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  This requires some minimal changes to my example since it can't work in one file, but that's fine.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVcAOBDAjgVwFMwAXAT02JIFUBnQgJwDtsBbYgXjFpIYEsmAcwDcGHASoUqABWy1aCOAwAmYLj35DRqKPiYBjEnzhMwAN2ww+y7CUJ1GACnz0GALlIPmbQgBowOPKKKh4kskFKygCUYADeqAC+6PomPGAujKFeLOxqYADkUHBwyvmiKUxpgbSh4QqRefnVZegWVjZ2Xo7V-hkMUcJAA

Comment: @Wazeem: Read the links more thoroughly. *"Opaque type aliases are type aliases that do not allow access to their underlying type **outside of the file in which they are defined**."* *(my emphasis)* It's true that the OP won't be able to just *cast* strings to his opaque types if I'm reading correctly, but then, that wouldn't be a very useful protection anyway.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that was my point. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Wazeem: Hardly seems worth downvoting over, particularly without saying *why* it doesn't do what (you think) the OP wants.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with the code above. In the first two lines you're *aliasing* the two variables to type `string`. Therefor, the two types are identical.

On the last line, the two values are still valid because both arguments are essentially of the same type. That is `string`. And `validateUser` expects strings.

To simplify this a little bit, consider the following:

```
function validateUser(user: string, password: string) {
}

validateUser('foo', 'bar');
```

The code in the original post, basically comes down to this. It is still valid.

If your types were more complicated (in other words, not identical) from the beginning, then you should expect some errors if you switched the arguments. For example:

```
type tUser = {
  username: string,
  id: number,
};

type tPassword = {
  hash: string,
};

function validateUser(user: tUser, password: tPassword) {
}

const user: tUser = {
  id: 1,
  username: 'mark',
}

const password: tPassword = {
  hash: 'abcd1234',
}

validateUser(password, user); // should throw
```

Comment: Yes, I know there's nothing wrong with the code.  The point is that I want it to throw.  I want to be able to tell flow that `tPassword != tUsername` even though they both resolve to a `string`.  So I want to change the type defs or function signature so that the call throws.

Comment: What you are suggesting can be possible in a nominal type system, which is not what flow is.

Comment: @Wazeem: From [Opaque Type Aliases](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/opaque-types/) in the Flow documentation: *"When importing an opaque type alias, it behaves like a [nominal type](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/nominal-structural/#toc-nominal-typing), hiding its underlying type."*